# I am getting null value of HttpPostedFileBase when edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to show uploaded image in image view during edit the form and then send that image to controller using input type file.

I am trying like below, but HttpPostedFileBase always return null value.

My View code is

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddUpdateCategory", "Categories", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "", OnSuccess = "", OnBegin = "", OnFailure = " }, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "CategoryForm", novalidate = "novalidate" }))
```

{

```
<div class="file-upload ">
    <button class="file-upload-btn" type="button" onclick="$('.file-upload-input').trigger( 'click' )">Add Image</button>
    <div class="image-upload-wrap">
        <input class="file-upload-input" type='file' name="file" onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" />
        <div class="drag-text">
            <span> Drag and drop a file or select add Image</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="file-upload-content">
        <img class="file-upload-image" src="@Model.Base64String" alt="your image" />
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.FileName)
        <div class="image-title-wrap">
            <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove-image">Remove <span class="image-title">@Model.FileName</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

}

Below is my controller code.

```
public ActionResult AddUpdateCategory(Category objCategory, HttpPostedFileBase file, FormCollection fc)
    {

        using (HttpClient client = GetHttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                if (file != null)

                {
                    var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                    var fileid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + extension;
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Category/"), fileid);

                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    objCategory.ImageURL = fileid;
                }



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error while uploading the files.");

            }

        }
        return Json(new { ModelState }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Without knowing your forms code, it will be very difficult to help you. Maybe the name of your file input is not `file`? Please update your question with more details.

Comment: I have update my post please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in your form tag

Comment: And, indeed, you are also missing the form. file inputs need a form with the mentioned `enctype` to function properly.

Comment: My form have all the attribute which required for file uploading and also my input field(file) have same name as in my controller action (param). Is there any way to set the input type file value?

Comment: Can you show us your whole html code where form tag is visible? In your view code there is no form tag at all.

Comment: You can check working example [here](http://www.compilemode.com/2016/04/uploading-files-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-HttpPostedFileBase.html)

Comment: I have add form please check now.
My coding is working fine when i select file from computer. but when i edit form and show image in image view using Base46string and then update a from with out selecting the file form computer. I am asuming that i will get the viewed image in httppostedfilebase.